# How to get IndexPath first section tableview of subcell using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create accordion `tableview`. here I can get easily `parent tableview` selected cell index path values but I cant get subtable (Expandable `child` tableview cell) `row index path`. Please give me any solution for my issue and find below code

My Code :

```
// @optional
- (void)didSelectRowAtChildIndex:(NSInteger)childIndex underParentIndex:(NSInteger)parentIndex {

    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self rowForParentIndex:parentIndex] inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([selectedCell isKindOfClass:[ParentTableViewCell class]]) {

        //ParentTableViewCell * pCell = (ParentTableViewCell *)selectedCell;

        // Insert code here to detect and handle child cell selection
        // ...

    }
}
```

I am checking by open source code : https://github.com/ajkoshy7/SubTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get indexpath of selected Child from childIndex:

```
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self rowForParentIndex:parentIndex] inSection:0];
NSIndexPath * indexPathChild = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self rowForParentIndex:childIndex] inSection:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! @Irfan

Comment: Glad it helped you. Also check the modified answer.